# How to (concisely) fill in only the missing values/cells in a data frame by joining tables

Tags: r, function, join, data-wrangling, across

My problem: I had missing values in a data frame (original_df). After a while I received new data for the original observations for some columns (new_df). I wanted to update the original_df accordingly. Data that wasn't missing priorly should be untouched.

As I understand, this is neither a job for row_bind nor for joins. Here is what I did (and was sufficient), but it seems very repetitive. I wanted to write a function for this, but this didn't work somehow.

```
#overwrite cells with new values in old table

#join with renaming of new columns (+ .y)
original_df <- left_join(original_df, new_df, by="ID", suffix = c("", ".y"),)

#overwrite old data with data from new columns
original_df <- original_df %>% mutate(col_a = ifelse(!is.na(col_a.y),
                                                  col_a.y, col_a)) %>%
  mutate(col_b = ifelse(!is.na(col_b.y),
                             col_b.y, col_b)) %>%
  mutate(col_c = ifelse(!is.na(col_c.y),
                           col_c.y,col_c))

#delete new columns
original_df <- original_df %>% select(-contains(".y"))


#more concise try but not working
update_cell <- function(new_data){
  old_data <- paste(new_data, ".y", sep="")
  if_else(!is.na(new_data), new_data, old_data)
}

original_df %>% mutate(across(update_cell(c(col_a, col_b, col_c)), update_cell(.)))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Sorry for not contributing the original data, which should be kept private.

Thanks in advance!
Best regards.

Comment: `old_df[is.na(old_df)] <- new_df[is.na(old_df)]` if the dimensions are the same.

Comment: this looks like {powerjoin} could do it but it's not easy to understand without sample data. You should build a minimal example from your real data, and when it's small enough anonymise it.

Comment: try `library(powerjoin); power_left_join(original_df, new_df, by="ID", conflict = coalesce_yx)`

Comment: `dplyr::rows_update()` might also work